# mongocxx cursor and rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver

I was looking to [the mongocxx query exemples](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/query.cpp) and I don't get whats the point of using `auto&&` over `auto&` here.

```
auto cursor = db["restaurants"].find({}, opts);
        for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
            std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
```

In the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/), they use it this way:

```
mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find(document{} << finalize);
for(auto doc : cursor) {
  std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << "\n";
}
```

I want to use `for(auto& doc : cursor)`

What is the best practice here, and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this bit:

```
for (auto&& doc : cursor)
...
```

The *"range expression"* in *"range for"* can return a [temporary](http://scv.bu.edu/computation/bluegene/IBMdocs/compiler/xlc-8.0/html/language/ref/cplr382.htm).

It is a *"best practice"* to use rvalue reference here (when using `auto`).

Have a look at this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Quote:

> If range_expression returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the rvalue reference __range, but beware that the lifetime of any temporary within range_expression is not extended.

And this:

http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html

Quote:

> An rvalue reference behaves just like an lvalue reference except that it can bind to a temporary (an rvalue), whereas you can not bind a (non const) lvalue reference to an rvalue.